# How can I create a .net remoting IPC channel accessible from all sessions?

Tags: .net, remoting

If I have a Windows Service running in its own session (Session 0 isolation Vista/7), my GUI application in the users session cannot connect via .NET remoting using a IPC channel(named pipe). I do not want to use the TCP channel. Can I specify the channel as global?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was being created globally. I was in fact getting an access denied exception. Setting authorizedGroup="Everyone" on the channel fixed it.